# Re-evaluating CanExecute on property change

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I am trying to implement ICommandSource on a custom control (similar to a button). Currently the implementation is mostly like it is displayed on the msdn page for ICommandSource and as it shows in the ButtonBase source code.

CanExecute fires on load of the control but doesn't fire when any property has changed. The same command being passed to a regular button works just fine. When the property that is supposed to change changes, CanExecute fires and the button is enabled. The command is a Delegate Command.

I have tried CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); but that has not worked.

Any ideas?

Here's the implementation in the custom control:

```
private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CollapsibleSplitButton csb = (CollapsibleSplitButton)d;
    csb.OnCommandChanged((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
}

private void OnCommandChanged(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
{
    if (oldCommand != null) UnhookCommand(oldCommand);
    if (newCommand != null) HookCommand(newCommand);
}

private void UnhookCommand(ICommand command)
{
    command.CanExecuteChanged -= OnCanExecuteChanged;
    UpdateCanExecute();
}

private void HookCommand(ICommand command)
{
    command.CanExecuteChanged += OnCanExecuteChanged;
    UpdateCanExecute();
}
private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCanExecute();
}

private void UpdateCanExecute()
{
    if (Command != null)
        CanExecute = Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter);
    else
        CanExecute = true;
}

protected override bool IsEnabledCore
{
    get { return base.IsEnabledCore && CanExecute; }
}
```

Where I setup the Command I have:

```
...
    MyCommand = new DelegatingCommand(DoStuff, CanDoStuff);
...

private bool CanDoStuff()
{
    return (DueDate == null);
}

private void DoStuff() {//do stuff}
```

Comment: Its an INotifyChangedProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by wrapping the callback in an EventHandler.

```
private EventHandler currentHandler;

private void UnhookCommand(ICommand command)
{
    if (currentHandler != null)
        command.CanExecuteChanged -= currentHandler;
    UpdateCanExecute();
}

private void HookCommand(ICommand command)
{
    if (currentHandler == null) return;

    command.CanExecuteChanged += currentHandler;
    UpdateCanExecute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `delegate` commands, you have to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` explicitly whenever you think it should be updated on UI. Try using this version of command called `RelayCommand` -

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
   #region Fields

   readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
   readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

   #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.
    ///This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
       if (execute == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

       _execute = execute;
       _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current 
    ///state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require 
    /// data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require 
    ///data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And register like `Delegate` commands in your class-

```
public ICommand TestCommand { get; private set; }
TestCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(CommandMethod, CanExecuteCommand);
```

**EDIT**

Try putting `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` in your `CanExecute` -

```
private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    UpdateCanExecute();
}
```

Comment: My DelegateCommand is roughly the exact same code. just a few differences here and there. But no, this does not work either.

Comment: Nope. Still does not work. The regular Button still works properly, however, the Custom control does not. OnCanExecuteChanged on the custom control does not fire when I modify the property that needs to change. On the custom control OnCanExecuteChanged only fires when that viewmodel is loaded/reloaded.